# _muldi3_s.o is in unrecognized file format when compiling GCC

Tags: linux, gcc

I am trying to compile GCC from source on 64-bit Oracle Linux 7, and I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: _muldi3_s.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/bin/ld: _muldi3_s.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/bin/ld: _muldi3_s.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
/usr/bin/ld: _muldi3_s.o: unable to initialize decompress status for section .debug_info
_muldi3_s.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Makefile:992: libgcc_s.so] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/teo.samarzija/gcc-9.3.0-objdir/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:22952: all-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/teo.samarzija/gcc-9.3.0-objdir'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:29320: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/teo.samarzija/gcc-9.3.0-objdir'
make: *** [Makefile:1002: all] Error 2
```

Any idea what might be going on?
I configured it with `../gcc-9.3.0/configure --prefix=/home/teo.samarzija/gcc-9.3.0-build --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran,go,ada`.

Comment: guessing.. check how `_muldi3_s.o` is being built and whether anything differs from building other `.o` files; also `cd` to that dir and check if `file *.o` reports anything different between `.o` files; swag: maybe reduce config languages to c or c,c++

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38106